# C++ new operator allocate new memory

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was running a tiny program for fun and encountered a issue that puzzled me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct T
{
    int val;
};
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        T *p = new T;
        cout << p << endl;
        delete p;
    }

    T *q = new T;
    cout << q << endl;
    delete q;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0x16b76d0
0x16b76d0
0x16b76d0
```

They are all at same memory location?

Comment: Yes, they're all the same location *in this case*.  All your program is doing is reusing the same memory for the same object (and why not; after each `delete` it's no longer being used and is available for another allocation if the memory manager deems it appropriate, and in this case it does).

Answer (score 4):

You are deleting the memory after printing the address. Then the memory manager is free to choose the same address to allocate new memory.

Answer (score 1):

The **compiler** along with your **OS (Operating System)** decide which memory address to allocate to your dynamically allocated memory. When delete is invoked, the memory address a pointer was pointing to is no longer referenced. Hence, the compiler can take the liberty of utilising that same **memory address** for your **new allocations**. It's not something which we have control of at this level of programming.

Comment: Not so much with the compiler. The compiler's job is long over by the time the program runs and requests dynamic storage.